# How to change the "class" attribute of a Fragment from java code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

In my android app, I have defined a fragment in my xml layout. The code is below:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    class="com.example.shantaportfolio.ListFragment" />
```

But I need to change the `class` attribute of the fragment from my java code. How can I do it? which method use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `<fragment/>` by `<FrameLayout/>` in your .xml file

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
/>
```

and then use java code to add fragment programatically

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ListFragment fragment = new ListFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.list_fragment, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

you can get more details from
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to replace a `Fragment` implementation in the layout insert a "container element" into your layout and set the `Fragment` there:

in the layout:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
</FrameLayout>
```

In the code:

```
final FragmentTransaction tx = this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
tx.replace(R.id.fragment_container, aFragment);
tx.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot intercept `LayoutInflator` instantiating the declared fragment. But You can [replace()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) any fragment in your Activity with another afterwards.

**Update:**

You can use an Implementation of [`LayoutInflator.Factory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.Factory.html), and use its `onCreateView()` method to do something different for some particular tags in layout.

You provide this factory implementation to `LayoutInflator` using [`setFactory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#setFactory%28android.view.LayoutInflater.Factory%29)

Comment: actually, you can force `LayoutInflater` to instatiate whatever you want using [LayoutInflater.Factory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.Factory.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot alter Fragments which are declared in XML. Instead, declare a container where a fragment will belong and in the `onCreate()` method of your activity, attach a Fragment to this container. When you want to swap Fragments, simply use the `replace` method and specify which fragment you want to swap.
Note: containers are usually made with a `LinearLayout` by arranging them to the specific size. Below is a simple XML layout which provides a layout on the left which is 2/3 the screen size and another on the right which is 1/3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_child"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```